# What does the Zsh variable syntax of colon then letter suffix do?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

I am using a script on my iMac (Automator) that I found on macmost.com that contains the following lines:

```
#/bin/zsh
for f in "$@"
do
     filedate=$(mdls $f | grep kMDItemContentCreationDate -m 1 | awk '{print $3, $4}');
     filename=$f:t
     filepath=$f:h
     mv $filepath/{"$filename","$filedate $filename"}
done
```

It works fine but where can I find information about the extensions :t and :h?

Comment: `man zsh` might be a good place to start.

Comment: FYI -- The `#/bin/zsh` _shebang_ is missing `!`, it should be `#!/bin/zsh` and you should be putting _double-quotes_ around the _variables_ to prevent globbing and word splitting . E.g. `"$f"`, `"$filepath"`, `filename="${f:t}"` and: `filename="${f:h}"`

Comment: You are right and the first line was not in the script on macmost.com, my mistake.

Comment: @user3439894 In zsh, double quoting is not necessary (except in a small number of cases that do not apply here). Even in sh, double quotes are not necessary in assignments (but they are in some very similar contexts, so they're a good habit).

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil', Thanks for the info! -- I typically use `bash` and run my _shell scripts_ thru [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and it often suggests _double-quotes_  where it isn't absolutely necessary, however, I've just gotten into the habit of using _double-quotes_ for most things except where I know it actually can be problematic. Since **macOS** has moved to `zsh` I guess one of the days I'll start reading the **The Z Shell Manual**, which I have as **PDF** and **HTML** documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those "extensions" are actually modifiers. The syntax comes (is copied) from the Tenex C shell. More info here- https://web.cs.elte.hu/local/texinfo/zsh/zsh_23.html

Comment: Thank you. This question will not be known as the brightest. I (age: 70) had forgotten the term 'modifier' ... I found a simple blog after this: https://www.tlbx.app/blog/zshell-path-modifiers.